# How do I remove a font from Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts

A page I visit frequently uses "Segoe UI" as the primary font, but it looks terrible on my XP machine at work.

I've attempted to remove the font from Windows so the site will use Verdana again, but windows will not let me remove it, it always says the font is "is use."

How can I keep firefox from loading Segoe UI when I surf the web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the font request embedded in the HTML tags, or more likely CSS?

If it's in the CSS styles, there probably are some plugins like [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) that let  you override CSS on a per site basis.

Or you can also [edit your userContent.css](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.support.firefox/cwV3WTcRoJU) with some Mozilla/Firefox specific CSS for that site.